# Hudson - how to trigger a build via file using the filename and file contents

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Currently I'm working in a continuous integration server solution using Hudson.

Now I'm looking for a build job which will be triggered every time it finds a file in a specific directory.

I've found some plugins which allow Hudson to watch and poll files from a directory (File Found Trigger, FSTrigger and SCM File Trigger) but none of them allow me to get the filename and file contents from the file found and use these values during the build execution (My idea would pass these values to a shell script)

Do you guys know if this is something possible to do via any other Hudson plugin? or maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks,
Davi

Comment: Can't you just query for this information during the build, from a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Two valid solutions:

- As suggested by **[Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234938/christopher)**, read the values from the file via Shell/Batch commands at the beginning of your build-script.
  (The downside is that Hudson will not be aware of those values in any way)
- Use the **[Envfile Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Envfile+Plugin)** to read the content of the file and interperate it as a set of key-value pairs.

Note that if the *File Found Trigger* "eats" the flag-file, you may need to create two files -
one to hold the key-value pairs and another to serve as a flag for the *File Found Trigger*.